# What to do when git on PC will not change account

Tags: git, github

At the start of the year I downloaded github desktop but have now deleted it in favour of tortoise git.

I have been happily doing git push to repositories in my WORK account using https.

I have now set up my OWN account on github with NEWREPO repository.

the remotes and user details are set correctly as seen using git config --list

user.name=own

user.email=owner@gmail.com

remote.origin.url=https://github.com/OWN/NEWREPO.github.io.git

remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to OWN/NEWREPO.github.io.git denied to WORK.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OWN/NEWREPO.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Having checked for error on Google and following advice have found ssh keys (presumably set up by github desktop as I didn't do it) which I deleted and have reset user.name and user.email both globally and within a folder but still somehow the PC is locked into WORK.

I want to continue using https not ssh any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git probably still has your [old credentials saved.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

Comment: Having read more on credentials ended up manually removing the relevant lines in .git config